# Relation of pH and amino acids in microtitr assay

Tags: microbiology, lab-reagents, ph, growth-media, extremophiles

I am testing a Biolog plate (https://www.biolog.com/products/metabolic-characterization-microplates/) in which the wells test for the optimum pH at which my bacterium grows. Aside from having a range of pHs (3.5 - 10), two pHs (4.5 and 9.5) are tested with a range of amino acids (and some other compounds such as urea).

My question is why would there be any interest of testing these amino acids at two different pHs. My guess is just to test for any oligotrophys but on the other hand they could have then prepared these assays with any other set of random compounds. Is there any specific to amino acids and pH that I am missing.

Here is the picture of the different compounds tested in the micro-titter plates. [image]